# Manga with a main character that had two spirits or helpers he could summon

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga a long time ago, but forgot what it was called. I remember that the main character had like two spirits or helpers he could summon. One was a fox-girl who had anger issues. I don't remember what the other one was.

He had an ability where he had a separate world with villagers. In that world, they couldn't see him, but they worship him as a God. And then he meets this knight. She was a guard of a princess from a kingdom and was about to be sold as a slave. He saves them and transports them into his world and then brings the slave trader to his world. There's no magic in that world, so the villagers beat him up, then he sends him back. The princess of that kingdom asks him to marry her, or to be the queen of the place.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: @LogicDictates yes it was mostly black and white

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be ***[Tenohira Kaitaku Mura de Isekai Kenkokuki](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tenohira-kaitaku-mura-de-isekai-kenkokuki)***.

From Anime-Planet:

> Kai who was reincarnated into different world, thrown away by the corrupt church into an isolated island full of dangerous demons. The key to surviving on the island is the Kai's Cheat ability to summon a different world's item that Kai has used before. With this ability, he builds a "Pioneering Village". Kai's survival & the fate of the national life! It is a different world ability that only you can enter, cute girls and survival life!

The protagonist, Kai, received a blessing from a god that allows him to transport himself to another world which he's in charge of, sort of like a city-building video game. He starts by farming an empty field and gradually establishes a village there. However, aside from one girl, none of the villagers can see him, because he's the god of that world.

Later on in the story, Kai saves a mage from some mercenaries and she subsequently reveals that she was the guardian of a princess, and asks Kai to help her rescue the princess, who's still in the clutches of a powerful slave trader. They rescue the princess together, and then Kai transports one of the slave traders, a magician, to his village. The magician attempts to use his magic there, but it doesn't work in that world, and he receives a beating from some of the villagers.

Kai acquires a number of female companions in this story, including a girl with fox ears and a tail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: yeah this is it thank you